# Circular progress view track tint color change in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, c#-4.0, xamarin.ios

I am using DACircularProgress for progress view . I want it to look like as

[image]

But i can't manipulate any of it's property except TrackTintColor which is always clear . I used LabeledCircularProgressView. Is this even possible with DACircularProgress.Is there any other solution? I tried RadialProgress but it does not support the progress shown as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set a `Progress` to show the Value? You can use `ProgressTintColor` to change the progress's tint color, and use `ProgressLabel` to modify the label which is in the center of the ProgressView:

```
LabeledCircularProgressView progressView;
progressView = new LabeledCircularProgressView(new CGRect(50, 40, 40, 40));
progressView.TrackTintColor = UIColor.LightGray;
progressView.ProgressTintColor = UIColor.Red;
progressView.ProgressLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
View.AddSubview(progressView);
```

Set a `progress` to see this effect:

```
//Please notice that this value should be between 0 - 1
progressView.SetProgress(0.5f, true);
progressView.ProgressLabel.Text = "36";
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply .Your solution really works . 
My mistake was giving value above 1 for progressView.SetProgress(0.5f, true);